# Change account photo from webcam after installation

Tags: installation, 12.10, login, webcam, photo

I took my profile photo during installation of Ubuntu 12.10. Now I'm trying to change it, but I see only choices to select an image from files. How to re-acquire the image with the attached webcam?

Comment: Do you want to take a new picture or just attach the picture you took earlier?

Comment: @Jobin The question asks "How to re-acquire the image with the attached webcam?" So Sergey is asking how to take a *new* picture.

Answer (score 1):

Use an application like Cheese Webcam Booth (`sudo apt-get install cheese`) to take the photo, save and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is understood that external tools can be used to take pictures. The question was, is it possible to use just that same simple tool employed during installation?

Comment: So you **don't want to install additional software**? Then please add that condition in your question just to make things clear to people.